# Dialog box background color on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

In my application, I show alert if the GPS location invalid:

`Dialog.alert("Current Location info not available..");`

I want to change the default background color and text color of the dialog alert. I need transparent silver color. How to create a custom dialog alert on Blackberry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show custom dialog you need to create custom class by extending PopupScreen.

Like below.

```
class CustomPopUp extends PopupScreen
{

    public CustomPopUp(Manager delegate)
    {
        super(delegate);
    }
}
```

After creating custom class you need to take Manager like.

```
 VerticalFieldManager pop=new VerticalFieldManager();
 pop.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLUE));
 LabelField lf=new LabelField("Invalid Location");
 ButtonField btn=new ButtonField("OK",DrawStyle.HCENTER);
 pop.add(lf);
 pop.add(btn);
```

Push Screen when you want to display dialog like below.

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(pop);
```

On Button Click listener call

```
 UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(pop);
```

Hope This will help you

Comment: search methods in BackgroundFactory

Comment: But we can't change dialog box default color ah?

Comment: we can't change dialog box default color

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3647/discussion-between-ganesh-rao-and-koti)