# How to display a popupScreen in Blackberry Application?

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, popup

how can i call the popupScreen on top of my main screen. it functions as a user login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link will help you to find solution for push the popup screen on the top of the main screen

[Dialog box background color on Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494643/dialog-box-background-color-on-blackberry/7495051#7495051)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of the SDK you are using but I've used the following:

```
DialogFieldManager manager = new DialogFieldManager();
PopupScreen popup = new PopupScreen(manager);
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(popup);
popup.doPaint();
```

Comment: since it is being used for a login screen, and presumably @roses_r wants to wait for the login credentials, I would remove the call to `popup.doPaint()`, use `UiApplication.pushModalScreen()` instead of `UiApplication.pushScreen`(), and derive a class from `PopupScreen` that calls `UiApplication.popScreen()` when the user closes it.

Comment: Thanks Remy I got it sorted out Thanks very much :)